# Using two 2-pin power cable together as 4-pin (CPU ATX)

Tags: power-supply, cable, atx

My main-board needs 4-pin ATX CPU power, but my power supply (1000W) has two 2-pins. Can I use these two 2-pins together and how? Also, my power supply has 6-pin and 8-pin cables too.

Power supply model: ENERMAX (Plantimax) - EPM1000EWT

Comment: What power supply is it?

Comment: @gronostaj ENERMAX (Plantimax) - EPM1000EWT

Comment: https://www.enermax.com/home.php?fn=eng/product_a1_1_3&lv0=1&lv1=52&no=184  according to the manufactures website, it should come with a 4+4pin (8pin) cpu cable, you should use this. Edit: since the 4+4pin cpu cable is just an 8pin, you could maybe use half the 8pin cable if it fits.

Comment: And the 4+4pin cable looks like an 8pin cable until you look closer and discover you can split it into two parts. Use the correct 4pin part, and you are done.